# Generate Grouped Data with Exact Correlations, Means, and SD

Tags: r, anova, simulation, split-plot

I want to generate data with the following constraints. There is one factor and two numeric variables. Note that the desired mean structure is broken down by factor, which is what makes this a challenging problem.

Correlation between two variables is set (e.g., .50).

Mean/SD for group (there are two groups) are set (e.g., group 1 has a mean of 2 and 4 on the two variables, group 2 means of 4 and 6). SD can be set at 1 for all variables.

The code below provides a reproducible example.

```
library(MASS)  
out1 <- mvrnorm(40, mu = c(2,4), 
            Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5,
                             .5,1), ncol = 2),
            empirical = TRUE) #Generates data for first group  
out1<-as.data.frame(out1)   
out1$ivbg<-NA   
out1$ivbg<-1 #identifies group 1

out2 <- mvrnorm(40, mu = c(4,6),Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1), ncol = 2),
            empirical = TRUE)
out2<-as.data.frame(out2)  
out2$ivbg<-NA  
out2$ivbg<-2

merged<-rbind(out1,out2) # Put them together

cor(out1$V1,out1$V2) #Group 1 correlations = .5
sd(out1$V1) #Group 1 SD = 1
sd(out1$V2) #Group 1 SD = 1

cor(out2$V1,out2$V2) #Group 2 correlations = .5
sd(out2$V1) #Group 2 SD = 1
sd(out2$V2) #Group 2 SD = 1

cor(merged$V1,merged$V2) #Merged Correlation = .75
sd(merged$V1) #Merged sd = 1.414
sd(merged$V2) #Merged sd = 1.414
```

The mean structure is correct but my goal is to generate a dataset that retains the variance/covariance structure (i.e., r = .5, sd = 1.0).

EDIT: Goal is to end up with a set of 80 scores. Half of them have a mean of two, the other half a mean of 4 on the first variable. For the second variables, means of 4 and 6, respectively. The correlation between the two variables needs to be .5 for the entire 80 cases. The sd needs to be 1.0 for the entire set of 80 cases.

Comment: One problem with presenting code is it can be hard to distinguish between mistakes in the ideas (the algorithm you intend) and mistakes in implementation (what code you actually wrote). It's much easier if you clearly explain the idea so that we're not conflating two sets of issues (and then we're not stuck trying to debug your code - which is off topic here). When you say the variables are correlated is this intended to be conditional on (i.e. within) factor level? Or ignoring the factor (looking at marginal correlation), even though this changing of means with factor will impact correlation?

Comment: The endpoint is want is this - a set of 80 scores. Half of them have a mean of two, the other half a mean of 4 on the first variable. For the second variables, means of 4 and 6, respectively. The correlation between the two variables needs to be .5 for the entire 80 cases. The sd needs to be 1.0 for the entire set of 80 cases.

Comment: Are those population values or sample values that you want to specify?

Comment: I want my data to have those exact values. So I guess you'd call it sample values

Comment: I find this question well-posed, but I must wonder--why?  The distribution of this data will be very odd, since you are conditioning on so much.

Comment: This sort of approach underlies necessary calculations for statistical power analysis. You model expected parameters - the data generation is a simple (usually) tool to accomplish a wide range of calculations resulting in reasonable estimates of power.